# WDS prompt for password

Tags: windows, deployment, password, wds

Issue: I setup a new WDS server. Earlier with my old server, whenever a client pressed F12 to connect to the WDS, it would prompt them to select 'Windows Deployment Server' or 'Hard disk drive' and then when they chose the first option, it prompted for a password (a non-domain one setup just for that purpose). I don't know how this was done because with my new server its not happening and any man and his dog is now able to connect to my WDS and start the process (although they won't be able to go much further than selecting an image, because after that they again have to enter a domain credential before it proceeds). This exposes my WDS and the list of images I have on it. Could anyone advise how to setup a password even before it lists the images to choose from?

Comment: Disable PXE in the BIOS and set a BIOS password, would be another option.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable which computers your WDS server responds to. You can respond to all clients, all known clients, and no clients.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732360.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Is securing your Install Images a solution?  See this TechNet [article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/11827.securing-installation-images-in-windows-deployment-services-wds-en-us.aspx) for more details.